# how to run batch file in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I tried using very simple HTML to create several links to several batch files on my server that are intended to run when users click on the links. Using Chrome, every time I click on one of those files my browser displays the script itself (even though its a .bat) and doesn't actually run the script. Internet Explorer runs it every time, however all the users on the network use Chrome for web browsing.

Is there any way to force Chrome (preferably through HTML or VB or some other scripting on the page itself rather than change all of the users' browser settings) to run these batch files when the user clicks on the link?

Comment: Run on your server or on the client's machine? If the latter, you cannot do this. If the former, you need to make a call to a server side script which will then run those scripts. Even if you could run them directly, that's a very bad idea given potential validation and security issues.

Comment: Exact and I literally mean it, exact replica of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020734/how-to-run-batch-file-in-chrome
Yeah I heard it, I am Sherlock Holmes :D

Answer (score 1):

The answers given so far - that it's "not possible" - are incorrect or outdated. Using Chrome Apps you can call executables (called "hosts") if they are registered with Chrome. Of course a Chrome App is a client application so you need to distribute it.

See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#examples

Answer (score 0):

HTML, JS on browser cannot run shell command, command line. You have to implement server script to execute your bat file then call it from HTML, JS via Ajax or direct link.